# Can I execute a parent method in the namespace of a child?

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a class Foo in its namespace Bar:

```
namespace Bar;
class Foo
{
    public function main()
    {
        // This will be Bar\Biz
        return new Biz();
    }
}
```

The main() method returns class Bar\Biz

I would like to extend this class with no changes other than returning MyBar\Biz rather than Bar\Biz. I can do it like this:

```
namespace MyBar;
class myFoo extends Bar\Foo
{
    public function main()
    {
        // This will be MyBar\Biz
        return new Biz();
    }
}
```

Method main() is identical to the parent method. It just happens to run in a different namespace. This works.

However, main() is a long and complex method and I do not want to duplicate all its code and have to keep my copy synchronized with the source class that I am overriding. Is there a way to do this without having to duplicate the code?

I'm on PHP5.4, but I would be interested if there are solutions for later versions of PHP if it cannot be done in 5.4 (I am aware there is some kind of "import" in 5.6 that may be a solution?)

Comment: Here is the code in question: https://github.com/academe/laraveldkim/blob/master/src/MailServiceProvider.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the result into its own function and override that instead.

```
namespace Bar;
class Foo
{
    public function main()
    {
        // lots of logic
        return create();
    }

    protected function create() 
    {
        return new Biz();
    }
}


namespace MyBar;
class myFoo extends Bar\Biz
{
    protected function create()
    {
        return new Biz();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't be touching Bar/Foo. I am overriding it because I can't fix it how I want it. However, it is a good point and maybe a pull-request to source project would be accepted. At the very least, Biz could be a constant set in Foo, and overriding that constant could be all I need to do.

Comment: I'll leave this open for a day to see if there are any other approaches. If none, I'll accept this as the answer, as I can see it is likely I can't avoid some change being needed on the source project.

Comment: I will request that the source project does not hard code the class name in but references it, perhaps by defining `public static $class = 'Bar';` which can be overridden, and creating an instance with `new static::$class();` or something like that.